# String compare value and pull exact value of cells from other columns and copy to new cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to make a statistics table for a set of data and would like a formula that would find exact matches in string values in a particular column and pull the data from another column of that row if there is a match.

Basically, if "Name_1" appears in column X, copy the value of column Z from that row and paste it to a new cell.

[image: Raw Data in spreadsheet]

```vb
=IF(AND(Data!N:N,"*Name_1*",Data!O:O,"*HE*"),
        VLOOKUP(AND(Data!N:N,"*Name_1*"),Table2,15,FALSE))
```

I have multiple conditions that I would like the formula to check first before pulling the data.

If the cell in column N contains the name & if column O contains "HE" THEN,
copy value of cells found in column O (without repetition).

EDIT:

I am keeping track of the number of times (for example), CH appears in column N and the string value of the cell in the next column O. So I have a counter that counts every time CH appears - and the type of human error that has occurred (which is data in Column O).
Example of expected output:

| USERS | ERROR TYPE |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CH | HE1 |  |  |  |
| KL,LT | HE3 |  |  |  |
| CH | ABC |  |  |  |
| CH, KL, LT | HE1,HE2 |  |  |  |

Here, total count for CH is 3, with 2 involving HE1 and HE2 and 1 involving ABC (based on example).
Count for KL is 2 involving HE1, HE2 and HE3
Count for LT is 2 involving HE1, HE2 and HE3.

Comment: Put few sample data as text table to your post.

Comment: Hello @Harun24hr, I have added an image of the data I wish to work with, I hope it adds more clarity. Based on the image, 'CH' appears 2 times and involves "HE (Clerical) and HE (Technical)"

Comment: To me it is still not clear what you want to achieve. It would help if you provide the **expected output** along with your data - best thing is to use [Markdown Table Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) - then it is much easier to help you.

Comment: @Ike would I put the expected output using the table generator here in the comments or edit the main post? Sorry, i've never used this generator before I'm not sure how the formats would show

Comment: You should always update the question - reading [ask] and [repro] should help you to improve your question.